# Can't find beach items on SimCity Buildit

Tags: simcity-buildit

The newest iOS update of Simcity Buildit has the option to create a beach, but I can't find those beach items (Tokyo items can be earned through the airport). So I was wondering if the only way is to pop bubbles or is there something that I'm missing.

[image: SIMCITY-BEACH]

Comment: you're not the only person popping bubbles, have you visited the market? how about your friends? the NPC always has items for sale needed for expansions. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah just pop bubbles, I just got 1 item from just popping bubbles you gotta be lucky though.

Comment: there are more ways than that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to always visit your friends, and public market. You will often find items in other cities as well.

Most importantly, the NPC friend/city ALWAYS has 6 items for sale every 24 hours. 1 of those items will be from the category of non-makeable/non-purchaseable items (items to upgrade inventory, expand region and now beach property expansion items.

Make sure you regularly check the market. Though you may not be getting lucky, others may be and are more than willing to sell. Be prepared to be quick to the draw, and willing to spend big money on them. If you don't see an item, keep the market open and refresh it after 30 seconds (timer on the bottom)

Additionally, the game has a limit/requirement as to how many bubbles are active. If you upgrade your buildings to max and don't place new residential zones, so basically nothing to upgrade, you will get a ton of blue bubbles to pop nonstop. Whether they produce a rare item is still random however.

Comment: Additionally, they are getting much more prevalent on the global market lately as I believe many players are finished expanding their beaches and sell any beach items that pop up. (Myself included.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get beach expansion items is to watch videos by tapping on the thought bubble above random buildings with a film reel inside it. This, however, isn't very reliable for a few reasons. The first reason being those beach expansion items as possible prizes are not guaranteed, and there isn't a way to control if you get the expansion items or what beach items you end up getting. The second reason is that even if you somehow have a beach item that you want, there is a high chance you will not get the item, as it is randomized which item goes in which box. 
However, if you are lucky, this is still a possible method for expansion items.